# Is it possible to read a combination of a System Property and a Customized Property in Spring config file?

Tags: spring, properties, system, customization

I need to know if its possible in Spring to derive a value for a Property by combination of a System-Property and a Customized-Property defined over a PropertyFile.

**What I've done:**

1) Configured a -D argument in server as : -Dapp.Env="dev" 
2) In my spring-config.xml, defined datasource details as below:

```
<!--  DataSource configurations -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="myDataSource" />
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName" value="${my.database.xaDriver.class}" />
    <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>

            <prop key="URL">#{systemProperties['appEnv']}.${my.database.jdbcUrl}</prop>
            <prop key="user">#{systemProperties['appEnv']}.${my.database.user}</prop>
            <prop key="password">#{systemProperties['appEnv']}.${my.database.password}</prop>

        </props>

    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${my.database.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${my.database.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="borrowConnectionTimeout" value="60" /> 
    <property name="maintenanceInterval" value="120" />  
</bean>
```

3) Defined the following properties in my .properties file:
my.database.xaDriver.class=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource 
my.database.initialPoolSize=2 
my.database.maxPoolSize=10 
my.database.minPoolSize=2

dev.my.database.jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@test.com:1535:myDb 
dev.my.database.user=myuserid 
dev.my.database.password=mypwd

4) Defined .properties file location in the spring-config.xml as :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.properties" />
```

**What I get on start of server :**

Throwable occurred: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.database.jdbcUrl' in string value "#{systemProperties['appEnv']}.${my.database.jdbcUrl}"

**What I also tried :**

5) Defined a property in .properties file as below: 
app.Env=dev

6) Modified the datasource bean configuration as below:

```
            <prop key="URL">${app.Env}.${my.database.jdbcUrl}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${app.Env}.${my.database.user}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${app.Env}.${my.database.password}</prop>
```

However on start of server, I get same exception message :

Throwable occurred: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.database.jdbcUrl' in string value "${app.Env}.${my.database.jdbcUrl}"

Can someone help me out in pointing out what mistake I might be doing and what is/are the possible fix for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can read system properties into Spring bean:

```
<bean id="systemProperties" class="java.lang.System" factory-method="getProperties"/>
```

and then use [multiple property resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686635/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-my-applicationc)

2) You can use flag `systemPropertiesMode` of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

3) You can write your custom **bean factory** that would produce single `java.util.Properties` object from system properties and file properties.

That bean would have method

```
public Properties merge() {
    Properties merged = new Properties();
    for (Properties p : properties) {
        if (p != null) {
            merged.putAll(p);
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Invoked in spring like that:

```
<bean id="factory" class="my.Factory">
    <property name="properties">
        <util:list>
            <bean class="java.lang.System" factory-method="getProperties"/> 
            <bean ref="otherProperties">
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for the response, however can you pls elaborate more on step 3 ?

Comment: I've provided an example, note it's not a complete solution, but only as much code as needed to make concept clear