# Creating multiple instances of PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer - Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-bean

I have 2 different applications deployed in application server (glassfish). One is a jar file and other is a war application. Both the applications refer to a single properties file (data.properties). To read the properties file, I have created a instance of Springs **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** in respective context files (business-beans.xml and applicationContext.xml). After deploying the applications, I am able to load the properties file in one application while the other web application throws "Could not resolve placeholder 'sw.throttle.enable'

Question -

1. How to solve the issue?
2. Is it incorrect load the same properties file at two locations?
3. Is there a way I load the properties file in one context and in the other bean definition file use the reference of the first one?

SnapShot of business.beans

```
<bean   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${sw." />
    <property name="location"  value="file:///etc/data.properties" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Property referenced as below in business.beans

```
 <bean id="mService" class=" com.test.business.mService">
         <property name="throttlingEnabled" value="${sw.throttle.enable}"/>
    </bean>
```

Snapshot of applicationContext.xml

```
<bean   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${sw." />
        <property name="location"  value="file:///etc/data.properties" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Property referenced as below in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="downloadService" class="com.test.downloadService"
         init-method="startUp" destroy-method="shutDown"
         p:throttlingEnabled="${sw.throttle.enable}"  />
```

The application containing business.beans deploys well, but the application containing applicationContext.xml throw run time error "could not resolve placeholder sw.throttle.enable"

Note -

1. Both the applications are deployed in a OsGi Context.
2. Spring version is 3.0.1

Edit - 
The applicationContext.xml has another bean defined as below. Could this be the cause?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes it is the caause... Why do you need another one? It doesn't add anything to the already existing one.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can two propertie files be loaded in the same bean?

Comment: 1, 2, 100 sure... That is why there is a `locations` property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by setting "ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" to "true". Apparently business.beans had nothing to do with the issue

Below is the modified configuration which solved the issue

```
<bean   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${sw." />
        <property name="location"  value="file:///etc/data.properties" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceHolders" value="true"
    </bean>
```

Thanks [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686635/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-my-applicationc) for the answer +1