# Spring: how to autowire merged properties?

Tags: java, spring

in our modular application, we have multiple context:property-placeholder definitions, one for each module. Eg.:

applicationContext-module1.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:module1.default.properties,classpath*:module1.${runtime.environment}.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

applicationContext-module2.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:module2.default.properties,classpath*:module2.${runtime.environment}.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

etc.

@Value works great, for injecting single values, but I'd like to debug all configuration properties at once. Is it possible to autowire the merged properties read from all files?

Comment: what do you mean by "autowire the merged properties read from all files"

Comment: Something like this: @Autowired private Properties allProperties;

Comment: Can you try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534199/how-to-collect-spring-properties-from-multiple-files-for-use-on-a-single-bean)

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I have no problems with reading the properties from multiple locations. What I'd like to achieve is to inject all of the properties (read from different files) into a Map or Properties.

Comment: You can do that in a different java class.is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you please post a sample code?